# Is it possible to make a Demonic bite force for a demon with split mandible

Tags: biology, anatomy

I ADORE the design of the [Dragonbat](https://thecabininthewoods.fandom.com/wiki/Dragonbat) from The Cabin in the Woods. and I intend on making a similar region of anatomy for hellbound (sinister nightmare) bonnie the bunny, which is essentially just a stylized twisted [bonnie](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/fnaf-the-novel/images/b/bb/Twisted_Bonnie.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170611203233).

[image]
[*image source*](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/Z505GR)

but I also want it to be clear that the split in half mandible has the bite force of a grizzly bear, and I don't know where to look for ways to make anatomy of that kind feasible.
any resources/ideas as to how to make a split lower jaw while still having a hellishly bite force?

Comment: snakes have a split lower jaw, but covered in skin so it's not visible as has having a 3 part mouth from the exterior, even though it is exactly like that. I guess a snake scaled up could have a strong bite force regardless of the split jaw... the ancient titanoboa had a bite force of 900 psi and a bear has a bite force of 975 psi.  Sources : quick google search

Comment: altough I'm not sure if the titanoboa has a split jaw, some pictures of fossils depict it with a split jaw, but some drawings and representations don't... logically it was a snake that needed to swallow big things alive without chewing on them so it needed a jaw that could open completely, so it probably had the 3 way mouth.

Comment: Could you please translate the words dragonbat and bonnie into standard English? Not everyone speaks your local dialect. (I would even venture to say that *most* people don't speak it. It is clearly not any kind of mainstream dialect. For example, the Oxford English Dictionary does not list "bonny" or "bonnie" as a noun at all, only as an adjective, and the OED *will* list any meaning in any major dialect.) (And in case you wanted to write "feasible", why would you think that it is of Greek origin?)

Comment: @AlexP here: Bonnie: [link]https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/fnaf-the-novel/images/b/bb/Twisted_Bonnie.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170611203233

Answer (score 5):

There is only one animal that I have been able to find in nature that has a split jaw design similar to what you are talking about and that is the Splitjaw  Snake Bolyeriidae. Here is a link to an article that describes how their jaws work. https://www.thesciencebreaker.org/breaks/evolution-behaviour/snake-uses-its-split-jaws-as-a-knife-and-fork

While I am no expert on biology, from what I have been able to find out the type of jaw design you are going for does tend to compromise the ability to have a greater bite force and encourage the animal to simply swallow their prey whole.There is also the fact that they have skin covering both halves of the split jaw making it appear as if it were on normal unbrokent jawline, which would ruin the look you seem t be going for. If you are willing to bend the rules of normal biology a little, magic solves everything after all, I would suggest that you would take inspiration from this and have each half of the jaw enclosed in layer of scaled skin so that each half could act like its own independent mouth. When your Bonnie's mouth is closed the two halves could meet up to look like one unbroken jawline, like a normal mouth, and only reveal the split. If you liked the exposed bone look you could have your Bonnie grow osteoderms on its jawline, similar to the armor on an Ankylosaurus, to mimic the look. After that it is just a matter of providing a good enough narrative reason for your world building to explain the strength of the bite. I would suggest giving them very prominent muscles at the connection point between their jaws and skulls, similar to a pitbulls, thickened necks, and exceptionally strong teeth with a greater surface area.

Comment: I think Bonnie should just swallow things whole.

Comment: so I think im gonna go with BOTH of your ideas
Have smaller-esk hyena teeth at the front, grizzly bear-sized teeth at the back for BOTH parts of the mouth, but have Illusion Disk Magic be the excuse for sufficient bite force

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The part of he jaw that does the biting is behind the split. This part of the mandible has a bone plate on the bottom below the tongue to stop it cracking in half from the awesome power of its bite. The teeth on the front are only for grabbing stuff. The teeth at the back are for destroying stuff.

Comment: so Like have the front teeth be pretty intimidating yet still relatively small but then have the back teeth be Lovecraftian?

Comment: @JBmodelHopper Pointy needle teeth at the front for the grabby grabby. Chunky hyaena/bear teeth at the back for the crushy crushy.